# Load data in Dynamics CRM in entity having data type multiselect

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm

I am trying to load data in entity from Salesforce to Dynamics CRM via Azure data factory. One field of this entity `ava_subjects` is of  data type as Multiple select option. This column has value `English;Science`.

My question is how can I load data of this field in Dynamics CRM. I have tried loading with below option but I was unable to load data.

Tried below options:

> English;Science
>
> 100000000;100000001 (used corresponding value of labels)
>
> 100000000,100000001
>
> English,Science

Comment: Do you have any followup questions?

Answer (score 0):

From this [community thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/289990), it looks like some schematics is missing for importing multiselect picklist. That field needs exported file from CRM to maintain the schema.

> I export some data with Dynamics with the MultiSelect Option field included in the export.  Column G contains the MultiSelect Option.  The format of this column contains the parameters need for the Import.
>
> The data can be copied and pasted into this spread sheet and then used as the source file for an import into Dynamics.  The import layout can be bypassed since the spreadsheet contains both the data and the column format.  Apparently there are no Data Types in the Dynamics Import function that fit the MultiSelect Option Set, so this is the only way to import the MultiSelect Option Set data into Dynamics.

But we were able to import using Kingswaysoft connector with both text (English) or value (100000000) in `;` delimited string format.